# Reshei tevot question

Tags: acronyms

Please, I would like to know the meaning of the reshei tevot בנד"מ as found, for example, in a situation like בנד"מ דף י"ג ע"א. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't it stand for b'nidon- e.g it is an abbreviation for "in our discussion or in this case". And then at the end, the reference.

Comment: בנ as b'nidon sounds b'nidon, but what about the last part ד"מ. You may be thinking of בנדון דידן b'nidon didan (in our case; in the topic under discussion; lit. in our discussion), in which case I believe the reshei tevot would be בנדו״ד and not בנד"מ. What do you think?

Comment: That's what the page says- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hebrew_abbreviations#:~:text=%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9F%20%D7%93%D7%99%D7%93%D7%9F%2C%20%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%93%D7%95%D7%B4%D7%93%20(b%27nidon%20didan)%20%2D%20in%20our%20case%3B%20in%20the%20topic%20under%20discussion%3B%20lit.%20in%20our%20discussion

Comment: Yes, and, what do you think?

Comment: Personally, I haven't come across such a abbreviation. But, I think it is an reference to a source.

Comment: That's for sure. I understood it as well. I've seen this rather unusual reshei tevot in the Ohr HaChayim as well. Sometimes, these drive me crazy.

Comment: Can you include a reference to an example where you saw this used?

Comment: In Minchas Shlomo, by Rav Auerbach, this words are used when referencing to a source. When it discusses something, it is then said "in our case".

Comment: I did in the question itself. But I will add another. Here it is: אולם יש בענין זה שלושה אפשרויות שנזכרו בדברי רבותינו, והביאם הר"ן (בדרשותיו **בנד"מ** עמוד רפב).

Comment: Yep Shmuel, we already agreed it is a source-related indication. However, I am still not sure of its precise meaning, in my weak understanding.

Comment: Where does the phrase "בנד"מ דף י"ג ע"א" appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell it means בנדפס מחדש, i.e. the reference is to the pagination in the most recent printed edition.

Comment: I agree with you Joel. I just wrote about this but somehow the comment I made is not showing. I said that this reshei tevto appeas in a reference to the Rashash's Sefer Nahar Shalom apud Kerem Shlomo, like this: . וזה לשון אבי התעודה שר שלום זלה"ה בספר נהר שלום דף ל"ה עמוד ב' ול"ו עמוד א' [בנד"מ דף י"ג ע"א], (כי כל דבריו הם מלוקטים מפיזור דרושי הרב  ז"ל ולא ח"ו ממנו), וז"ל. The matter is this, the pagination used in the Kerem Shlomo reference is not the same as elsewhere, hence the parenthesis indicating an alternative and perhaps even more commonly used pagination of the Nahar Shalom.

Comment: @SimpleYid - if you believe it is right upvote and click the checkmark